# Parsing and printing XML with python

Tags: python, xml

I'm pretty new to XML and I was wondering how would I parse, sort, and print val1 to val4 in python? With my research I found `xml.dom` or `xml.etree` was used a lot but I'm having trouble finding the correct functions to use to parse the through the XML tree and print out what I need.

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <d>
        <item> val1 </item>
        <item> val2 </item>
        <item> val3 </item>
        <item> val4 </item>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

Comment: Parsing such a structure using an xpath '//item' or something similar is trivial. I do not see any personal effort, down voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently made a small python program to display some information from some XML files. I found that using [BeautifulSoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) made XML extremely easy to parse. You can either download the source from the linked website and install it yourself, or follow the documentation to install the package `bs4` using `pip` or `easy_install`.

Using BS4:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xmlFileORString);
for item in soup.a.b.c.d.find_all('item'):
    print(item.string)
```

**EDIT:** BS4 can also be compiled for Python 2.7 and the code is almost the exact same.

Comment: i was considering BeautifulSoup because it did look pretty straight forward but I decided to go with Etree or xml.dom, I can give that a try real quick

Comment: Beautiful soup is by far the best one I have found so far. You navigate through by simply calling the element names.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) lib:

```
from lxml import etree
xml = etree.XML(...)
for e in xml.xpath('//item'):
    print e.text
```

Here I have used [xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) to find all "item"-tags.

You can also write:

```
for e in xml.xpath('/a/b/c/d/item'):
    print e.text
```

If it is important to only find "item"s in the specified path.

Comment: I would chose lxml over beautifulsoup any day! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should find a good deal of information about XML. It's a very popular standard. You should familiarize yourself with the [Document Object Model (DOM) Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/) first. Most libraries build on that.

There are a few very popular python libraries available. Which one you chose depends on your personal needs.

[lxml](http://lxml.de/) -- Pretty much the de-facto standard when it comes to XML processing with Python. But quite frankly, the documentation sucks. But with a bit of time and effort, you'll get there.

[beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) -- The main aim of BS is *not* XML processing. It's main aim is to deal with input which might be messy (think screen-scraping). It has a very sexy API though, and might be enough for you.

[minidom](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) -- Included in the standard library, which in my opinion is a big plus. It offers you a simple way to load/write XML documents and exposes the aforementioned DOM level 1 spec. Nothing more, nothing less. For most small/simple projects this is more than enough. If however you need more advanced XML features like XPATH, XIincludes or XSL, or simply speed, look into `lxml`!

Hope this get's you started. Good Luck!

Comment: wow this was a very good review of my options. I'm trying BeautifulSoup right now. Originall i used lxml but I got a bit confused. I'll give it another shot after i tried BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1):

Use `lxml` package in python, because lxml supports to `xpath` which is very helpful for firing query on xml file. And it is fast to process large data from XML file

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(XML_FILE_PATH)
root = self.tree.getroot()
```

To get `text` from node of xml :

```
nodes =  tree.findall("//item")
text = [node.text for node in nodes]
```

You will get list i.e `[1,2,3,4]` , after that you can sort result list using `sorted(text)`

And for getting elements attributes, you can use -:

Suppose, `<item id="2" name="abc">1</item>`

```
entries = tree.xpath("//item[@id='2']")
```

You will get all attributes i.e `{'id':2, 'name':'abc'}` in `entries`